# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in RDotNet.dll to load R library in web application

Tags: c#, r, r.net

I am getting an error same error when loading "dplyr" library.

```
engine.Evaluate("library(dplyr)");
```

Above code me same error

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in RDotNet.dll".

Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance...

[The screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dknto.png)

Comment: Can you also provide detailed stack trace? Including stack trace often identifies your problem easier, also add related example codes if necessary (not just the line throwing exception).

Comment: Hi Tetsuya, i have attached the screenshot. Please look into this. The exception does not contain any stack trace, the exception is only one liner that i described in the question. Please refer the screenshot

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue with loading *dplyr* and other R libraries.  Turns out of the issue is with IIS and IIS Express having stack size of 256K on 32-bit and 512 K on 64-bit OS as mentioned [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/932909/by-default-the-maximum-stack-size-of-a-thread-that-is-created-in-a-nat).
You can get around this by either:

1) Creating a thread with a larger stack size and executing the R.NET commands inside of it.  For example:

```
Thread t = new Thread(MyMethodToDoRWork, 2500000 /*thread stack size of 2.5MB*/);
```

2) Change the default stack size of the IIS or IIS Express process via the EditBin tool (comes with Visual Studio).  See the example [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tom/2008/03/31/stack-sizes-in-iis-affects-asp-net/).  I don't recommend this however as you will be modifying the actual IIS/IIS Express binary file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the crash issue by adding all R code to the new thread. It runs perfectly. In debug mode I can even see that the R code is evaluated correctly! Code below (it is in VB but easy to covert to C#). Plus I included some more context that may help.

The catch is, now that we are in another thread, I cannot access the UI thread. Seems there's a great way to accomplish this in Win Forms using a UI's Invoke method but webcontrols don't seem to have this method. Hope this helps some.

```
Public Class SPF_R
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim t As System.Threading.Thread

...

Private Sub RunRStuff()

    Dim RCode As String = ""
    Dim engine As REngine = REngine.GetInstance(Nothing, True, Nothing)
    Dim myPath As String = ViewState("Folder") & ViewState("File")
    engine.Initialize()

    engine.Evaluate("library(MASS)") : RCode &= "library(MASS)" & vbCrLf
    engine.Evaluate("library(ggplot2)") : RCode &= "library(ggplot)" & vbCrLf
    engine.Evaluate("library(broom)") : RCode &= "library(broom)" & vbCrLf
   
    ...
   
End Sub

Private Function DevelopSPF() As Boolean

    cmdSPF.Enabled = False

    t = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf RunRStuff, 2500000)
    t.Start()

    cmdSPF.Enabled = True
    Return True

End Function

...
```